# Programming titles

Tags: data-request

Where can I find a list of job titles that programmers(or/and related specialties) have, e.g. mobile, web, developer, software engineer, co-founder.

For the list of programming languages, for example, I found [Stack Exchange Data Dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange).

Comment: check stack exchange jobs

Answer (score 3):

I would take a short list of programming langauges and then search those terms on a job website.

For example, searching [indeed.com](http://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=python&l=) for 'python' returns job titles of 'Data Developer', 'Build Automation Engineer', 'Software Engineer - Data Infrastructure', and 31502 more.

I mention indeed.com because they have an API that you can use code to perform searches - [LINK](http://www.indeed.com/jsp/apiinfo.jsp). You have to register to get the key, but it's free.

Once you've collected the thousands of job titles (and summary, descriptions, location, etc) for each programming language, you can do some basic stats to see which job titles are showing up most commonly (maybe the top 20 or something).

Comment: I'm not sure if mining indeed.com complies with their [AAUP](https://ads.indeed.com/jobroll/aaup.jsp) : 4. Prohibited Activities. Affiliate shall not: ... (h) redistribute the job search results or any part thereof to any third party, other than the provision of the job search results on Affiliate's website to the end users of that website that generated it; or (i) store any job search content

Comment: +1 for suggesting data mining indeed.com, +1 to @Joe for highlighting the limitations on redistributing the results of said data-mining.  If the OP's needs the results for personal reasons, redistribution prohibitions would be immaterial.